# JavaFX, how to prevent Label text resize during ScrollPane focus?

Tags: java, javafx, resize, focus, scrollpane

How do I stop the ScrollPane focus from resizing my Labels' text?

I'm making a copy of [this car loan calculator](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/loans/car-loan-calculator/) in JavaFX.

[Almost everything works as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0PP7.png)

[Until the ScrollPane gets focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCX2V.png), the title and text on right side gets resized

[A brief description of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjgct.png)

So, the problem is that my Labels' text is being resized when the ScrollPane gets focus.  I've tried fixing this by adjusting properties of the ScrollPane, the layouts contained within the ScrollPane, and the Labels themselves.  I also searched if a similar question has been asked before.  I've found nothing yet.

Thanks

Edit:

Added some code, I tried to keep it as minimal as possible. If you focus the TextField, all Label text is sized as expected. If you focus the ScrollPane, the big blue text sizes down to match the smaller black text.  There is obviously no need for scrolling in this example, but it still shows the issue I have with my project that does require scrolling.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontPosture;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Stage stage = primaryStage;

        HBox myHBox = new HBox();

        Label smallerText = new Label("this is small\ntext");
        smallerText.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
        smallerText.setTextFill(Color.web("#000000"));
        smallerText.setFont(Font.font("Leelawadee UI", FontPosture.REGULAR, 12));

        Label biggerText = new Label("this is big\ntext");
        biggerText.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
        biggerText.setTextFill(Color.web("#005FBA"));
        biggerText.setFont(Font.font("Leelawadee UI", FontPosture.REGULAR, 24));

        TextField myTextField = new TextField();

        myHBox.getChildren().addAll(smallerText, biggerText);

        VBox myVBox = new VBox();
        myVBox.getChildren().addAll(myHBox, myTextField);

        ScrollPane myScrollPane = new ScrollPane(myVBox);
        myScrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        myScrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);

        Scene scene = new Scene(myScrollPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Edit again:

Problem has been solved.  Thank you! :)

Comment: Why not just make sure everything fits in the window without a `ScrollPane`?

Comment: Depending on the values in the TextFields, additional text is added to the screen.  There isn't enough space to accommodate all text with the desired font size.

Comment: If you are using any css implementation, I suspect some thing is effecting from the css file. What I can notice is, on focus on scrollpane, all the font size is set to certain value. Can you post your css file.(if any)

Comment: I don't know enough about css to answer your question.  But, if I understand it correctly, some of the code does make css changes.  I've added example code in the post that might help clarify things.

Comment: Oh, there is an "application.css" file, but its only contents are the default comment.

Comment: can reproduce it (fx11 on win) - but no idea what triggers such a weird layout change ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suspected, something is effecting from the default CSS file implementation. You should definitely raise a JIRA ticket regarding this.

But for time being you can fix the issue, by moving all your style declaration to a css file. And everthing works as expected.

Below is what I had done.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FontResizeIssueOnFocus extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Stage stage = primaryStage;
        HBox myHBox = new HBox();

        Label smallerText = new Label("this is small\ntext");
        smallerText.getStyleClass().add("smaller-text");

        Label biggerText = new Label("this is big\ntext");
        biggerText.getStyleClass().add("bigger-text");

        TextField myTextField = new TextField();
        myHBox.getChildren().addAll(smallerText, biggerText);

        VBox myVBox = new VBox();
        myVBox.getChildren().addAll(myHBox, myTextField);

        ScrollPane myScrollPane = new ScrollPane(myVBox);
        myScrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        myScrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);

        Scene scene = new Scene(myScrollPane);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("scrollpanefontissue.css").toString());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

And in the css file...

```
.smaller-text{
  -fx-font-weight:bold;
  -fx-text-fill:#000000;
  -fx-font-family: "Leelawadee UI";
  -fx-font-size:12px;
}
.bigger-text{
  -fx-font-weight:bold;
  -fx-text-fill:#005FBA;
  -fx-font-family: "Leelawadee UI";
  -fx-font-size:24px;
}
```

Alternately, if you are not interested in css file implementation, you can declare using inline css. This will also fix your issue.

```
Label smallerText = new Label("this is small\ntext");
smallerText.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;-fx-text-fill:#000000;-fx-font-family:\"Leelawadee UI\";-fx-font-size:12px;");

Label biggerText = new Label("this is big\ntext");
biggerText.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;-fx-text-fill:#005FBA;-fx-font-family:\"Leelawadee UI\";-fx-font-size:24px;");
```

Comment: Fantastic!  This solves the problem I had in my project.  I opted to use the inline css.  I'd be happy to raise a JIRA ticket for this, but have no idea how to even begin doing so.  Do you (or anyone else) have a link to get me started?

Comment: It just fixed like a magic. Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I can't fix it via CSS, because I have to use computed padding value and utilizing something like `setStyle()` inside a listener is way too ugly. This is an obvious bug caused by the `requestLayout()` method which is set/called via ScrollPaneBehavior [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/jfx15/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/behavior/ScrollPaneBehavior.java#L87). When scroll pane receives focus it also somehow removes any inherited and content styles. So I've fixed this by stopping mouse event propagation:

```java
scrollPane.setOnMousePressed(Event::consume);
scrollPaneContentNode.setOnMousePressed(Event::consume);
```